# SQL - count occurrences in a column

Tags: sql

I would like to count values in a column (col2) that contains strings so that the a new column (count) returns the number of strings.

For example:

```
col1 | col2 | count
1    | dog  |  1
2    | cat  |  2
3    | cat  |  2
4    | bird |  1
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, you are working with Microsoft SQL Server, then you could use below `SQL` Script

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       COUNT(col2) OVER(PARTITION BY col2) AS cnt
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY col1;
```

Result :

```
col1 col2   cnt
1    dog    1
2    cat    2
3    cat    2
4    bird   1
```

Comment: this is exactly what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL offers window functions that do this:

```
select col1, col2, count(*) over (col2) as cnt
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very useful